# Azure AppInsights production deployment issue

Tags: visual-studio, azure, compiler-errors, production-environment, azure-application-insights

Recently I updated Azure Application Insights from version 1.0.0.4220 to Version 2.5.1.0, lot of files got updated and also some new stuff in web.config.

I then pushed my changes to UAT environment and then ran into the issue with web.config file, I was able to fix that when I copy pasted new wen.config into UAT environment.

Assuming same would be the change for Production, I copied the same new web.config into prod and the deployment was done.

Right after the release, we started seeing strange issues and errors in reference to AppInsights

See Attached images
[image]
[image]

eventually we had to revert back to last stable version, because none of our tries to fix the issue worked, and now we want to push the appInsights back into prod.

How can I make sure, I do not run into same issue ? I am not able the issue since, it works great in all test environments and also in UAT

Any suggestions will be helpful, Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that you have references to Application Insights in more than one project in your solutions and only updated the Nuget package for one of the projects? Have you looked at the differences in the Web.Config to see if the newer version maybe needs something the earlier version didn't?

Comment: Yes I did check the differences and in fact I did update production web.config too, just so I do not run into any errors, but for some reason, it would run into error.